# Why am I not allowed to use reference cell as argument for byref parameter in let functions?

Tags: f#

This doesn't work:

```
let increment(i: int byref) = i <- i + 1
let xxx = ref 0
increment(xxx) // this expression was expected to have type
               // byref<int> but here has type int ref
```

But this works:

```
let incrementParam(a: int byref) = a <- a + 1
let mutable b = 30
incrementParam(&b)
```

as well as this:

```
type Incrementor =
    static member Increment(i : int byref) =
       i <- i + 1

let fff = ref 10
Incrementor.Increment(fff)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the spec says so. See [Type Directed Conversions at **Member** Invocations](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818955) (emphasis mine), especially the following:

> Note: These type-directed conversions are primarily for interoperability with existing member-based .NET libraries and do not apply at invocations of functions defined in modules or bound locally in expressions.

Comment: Thx because I cannot find the restriction in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx so I asked

Comment: The article isn't clear about what applies to members vs functions. Although, the only example of this given is a member invocation.

Comment: +1 I was just copying bits of the specification for my answer too :-)

Answer (score 5):

To add some details to the reference that Daniel pointed out, the problem is that the type `'T ref` is not the same as the type `'T byref` and so the compiler needs to insert some conversion (to take the address).

I think this is only supported for members, because this is the main scenario (calling COM interop methods etc.) and because implicit conversions generally compilcate type inference. The type-directed conversions are an easier case where the compiler already knows the required type (`'T byref`). I suppose that, if this was allowed on functions, the compiler might infer that the type of argument should actually be `'T ref`.

If you want to get the first sample to work, you have to explicitly construct `'T byref` by taking the address of the `contents` field:

```
let increment(i: int byref) = i <- i + 1
let xxx = ref 0
increment(&xxx.contents)
```